# jQuery accordian arrow toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got an accordian toggle working great - but I have noticed that the arrow is not toggling when a link other than the 'active link' is selected. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.q').on(action, function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(speed)
    .siblings('.a').slideUp();
    var i = $(this).children('.q i');
    i.toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");

  });

});



.faq {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
.faq h4.q,
.faq div {
    margin:0;
    padding: 1.25em;
    position:relative;
    }
.faq h4.q {
    border-bottom: 1px #cdd4d9 solid;
    color: #eb9532;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right:3.1em;
}
.faq div.a {
    border-bottom: 1px #cdd4d9 solid;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.faq h4.q i {
    color: #bdc4c9;
    position:absolute;
    right:1.25em;
    top:1.25em;
}


<div class="faq"> 

<h4 class="q">Question 1<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
<div class="a">
<p>Answer 1</p>
</div>
<h4 class="q">Question 2<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
<div class="a">
<p>Answer 2</p>
</div>
<h4 class="q">Question 3<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
<div class="a">
<p>Answer 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `.q` from this `.children('.q i')`:

```
var i = $(this).children('i');
```

because `$(this)` is the `.q` element itself.

Comment: _that doesn't seem to be making a difference._ is actually not helping. Did it not worked or caused in some error? May be you should toggle the current class to the new one like `i.toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up");`

Comment: No it didn't work. The arrows are toggling when the active .q is clicked. (which is great) But I also need any 'open' .q to also toggle closed when another .q is clicked...